# Finding the limit of a sequence if recursive inequality holds

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, inequality, convergence-divergence

I am asked to show that the sequence $(x_n)$, $x_n>0 \, \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$   is convergent and find its limit knowing that $x_n(2a-x_{n+1})>a^2$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}, a\in \mathbb{R_+^*}$.

I showed, that it is bounded, because we know that $a^2>0$ so $x_n (2a - x_{n+1}) > 0 $, hence $x_{n+1}<2a$. I am having trouble showing that it is monotonic. It seems to be easy doing the following steps $x_n(2a-x_{n+1})= 2a x_n-x_n x_{n+1}> 2a x_n-2a x_{n+1}= 2a(x_n- x_{n+1})$ but how do I know that it is greatest than $a^2$? I also suppose that the limit should be $a$, because after that convergence is shown I can take the limits so the $<$ inequality changes to $\leq$. Is that right?
Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have

$2ax_n-x_nx_{n+1}>a^2$ , which gives $x_nx_{n+1}-2ax_n+a^2<0$. Then we must have $x_{n+1} \le x_n$. If not, then $x_{n+1} > x_n$ and therfore

$x_n^2 -2ax_n +a^2 <x_nx_{n+1}-2ax_n+a^2<0$, thus $(x_n-a)^2<0$, a contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

$$x_nx_{n+1}-x_n^2<-x_n^2+2ax_n-a^2=-(x_n-a)^2\leq0,$$
which gives that $x$  decreases and since $x_n>0$, we see that $x$ converges.

Let $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow+\infty}x_n=t$.

Thus, $$t(2a-t)\geq a^2$$ or
$$(t-a)^2\leq0,$$ which gives $t=a$.